# How to change map tile types on ui controls

Tags: javascript, here-api

When we are initializing the map, we set the baselayer to "reduced.day".
We are currently facing a problem, when the user changes the map type from "map-view" to "satellite" and back to "map-view", the tile changed to the standard and **not** "reduced.day".
I have looked up the docs, but can´t find any hint on how to prevent that problem.

So my question is, how to set with the UI controls the map-view tiles to reduced day.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally could achieve the solution for my problem.

The solution was to pass a custom object with the requested map style for each map type.
See below the complete code for editing the map controls.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Here Custom Controlls</title>
    <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"
    ></script>
    <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"
    ></script>
    <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"
    ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" style="height: 800px; width: 800px;"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      //Initialize the Platform object:
      const platform = new H.service.Platform({
        app_id: {YOUR_APP_ID},
        app_code: {YOUR_APP_CODE}
      });

      // Get the default map types from the Platform object:
      const defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

      // Instantiate the map:
      const map = new H.Map(
        document.getElementById("map"),
        defaultLayers.normal.map,
        {
          zoom: 10,
          center: { lng: 13.4, lat: 52.51 }
        }
      );

      const mapTileService = platform.getMapTileService({ type: "base" });

      var reduce = mapTileService.createTileLayer(
        "maptile",
        "reduced.day",
        256,
        "png8"
      );

      map.setBaseLayer(reduce);

      // Create the custom UI:
      const ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(
        map,
        {
          ...defaultLayers,
          normal: {
            map: reduce
          }
        },
        "de-DE"
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see two javascript functions codes.

SatelliteLayer will work with **type : 'aerial'**.

ReducedLayer will work with **type : 'base'**.

```
/**
 *
 * @param  {H.Map}
 * @param   {H.service.Platform}
 */
function setAerialSatelliteLayer(map, platform){
  var mapTileService = platform.getMapTileService({
      type: 'aerial'
    });
  var parameters = {};
  var tileLayer = mapTileService.createTileLayer(
      'maptile',
      'satellite.day',
      256,
      'png8',
      parameters
    );
  map.setBaseLayer(tileLayer);
}

/**
 *
 * @param  {H.Map}
 * @param   {H.service.Platform}
 */
function setBaseReducedLayer(map, platform){
  var mapTileService = platform.getMapTileService({
      type: 'base'
    });
  var parameters = {};
  var tileLayer = mapTileService.createTileLayer(
      'maptile',
      'reduced.day',
      256,
      'png8',
      parameters
    );
  map.setBaseLayer(tileLayer);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your answer right. We are able to set the base layer when we initialize the map. But where can we inject the function you mention to the controls? 

When we are using the map controls which changes the map schema to map-view, to satellite or to terrain, the schema will change to the default colorful schema when clicking on map-view and not reduced.day.

Comment: anything new from your site?